# How to assign a value to a constant variable which belongs to a structure?

Tags: c

```
struct temp{
const int i;
};
```

How do i initialize my variable 'i' inside the main() function?

Comment: You can't. It's a constant. Or you could maybe... But not really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot *assign* anything to a constant object. A constant object can only be *initialized* at the point of declaration, as in

```
struct temp t = { 5 };
```

I.e. you get only one chance. If you missed your chance to *initialize* a constant object, you are out of luck - the object will remain uninitialized forever.

For this reason it is generally not a good idea to create constant fields inside generally non-constant struct objects, unless you really know what you are doing.

That's the theory of it.

In practice you might sometimes see people resort to various "hacks" and simply ignore the constness of the field. For example, the whole struct can be "assigned to" by using `memcpy`. In some situations in C language you have no choice by to do something like that (with `malloc`ed objects, for example, since C language provides no means for supplying initializers in such contexts).

Again, C language is not very well suited to handling such types, which is why they should be used only in a very well planned contexts.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the struct initialiser, e.g.

```
int main()
{
    struct temp tester = { .i = 5 };
}
```

Comment: Working well. But You forgot to create an object over there....

Comment: @HarishR - whoops, cheers

Comment: This is a better example than AndreyT's because it is specific with what member it initializes.  His will only do the first element and set the rest to 0 - hope we don't add members to the top later.